# Why does the output output of hashes look like \x88H\x98\xda(\x04qQ vs �*�r?

Tags: python, encryption, character-encoding

I'm new to encryption, and programming in general. I'm just trying to get my head wrapped around some basic concepts.

I'm using python, Crypto.Hash.SHA256

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
```

In the REPL if I type

```
print SHA256.new('password').digest()//j���*�rBo��)'s`=
```

vs

```
SHA256.new('password').digest()//"^\x88H\x98\xda(\x04qQ\xd0\xe5o\x8d\xc6)'s`=\rj\xab\xbd\xd6*\x11\xefr\x1d\x15B\xd8"
```

What are these two outputs?
How are they supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: It is time in your career to learn about character encodings (ASCII, unicode), binary and binary encodings (hexadecimal, Base64). Learning this will serve you well. Wikipedia is your friend here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are using print, so Python is trying to convert the bytes to printable characters. Unfortunately, not every byte is printable, so you get some strange output.

In the second case, since you are not calling print, the Python interpreter does something different. It takes the return value, which is a string in this case, and shows the internal representation of the string. Which is why for some characters, you get something that is printable, but in other cases, you get an escaped sequence, like `\x88`.

The two outputs happen to just be two representations of the same digest.

FYI, when working with pycrypto and looking at hash function outputs, I highly recommend using `hexdigest` instead of `digest`.

Comment: Great answer thank you mikeazo.  So the escaped sequence \x88 is hexadecimal for 136?, and when i see \x04qQ what is that?

Comment: \x04qQ is `047151`. You have to be careful when trying to move from the printed out string and the representation. Sometimes, a character when printed can have a strange effect. Like a backspace, newline, etc.

Comment: When you see a `\x` prefix the next two characters are the hex representation of a byte that does not have a character representation. In this case `\x04` means a byte with the hexadecimal value 04.

Comment: Cryptographic function work on bytes, not characters so the output is binary, and most of the bytes are not displayable as characters. This is where hexadecimal and Base64 come in when a displayable version of binary is needed. Hexadecimal is best for people to understand the data and Base64 when an ASCII encoding is needed for computers.

Comment: @mikeazo The world has in general moved on from ASCII to unicode, it is more accurate to say many/most arbitrary binary bytes are not displayable as characters.

Comment: so when im looking at something being printed in ascii, (j���*�rBo��)'s) , how can I force it to show me the hex or base64 version?

Comment: Sorry I'm having such a hard time grasping this.  But how does \x04qQ = 047151??  \x04qQ doesn't appear to be valid hexadecimal

Comment: Instead of doing .digest() do .hexdigest()